# 'error' tag replacing with some 'meta refresh' tag

Tags: php, android, apache, https

I'm making a https request in android, and my response is something like this:

- `{"ResponseCode":52145,"Errors":{"error":"some error","description":"some description"}}`

Now from iphone client or even postman client on browser, this coming as expected. but in android, I am getting:

- `{"ResponseCode":52145,"Errors":{"<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=mydomain">":"some error","description":"some description"}}`

Difference:

```
"error" is getting replaced with "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=mydomain">"
```

my https headers are:

```
Accept = application/json
user-agent = android
```

If I use **http** instead of **https** everything is fine. So this makes me believe there is something definitely on server side related to security thing.

Main thing by which i am so curios is only "**error**" tag is getting replaced, even i am using "**Errors**" which is ok.

While I am not replacing at my end, server guy also make sure he is sending correct value. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: try to add header "contentType:application/json" OR "accepted:application/json"

Comment: yup, already there.. let me edit my question

Comment: Are you getting this issue in all your service calls ??
Make sure about the SchemeRegistry that you are using and port on Android...

Comment: I am getting this issue in every that response which have a "error" tag